# slideUp multiple divs

Tags: jquery, html, slideup

How can i make sure that several divs are slided up? Right now I have this function:

```
$("div#personal").click(function() { 
  $("div.1").slideUp("slow", function () { $("div.2").slideDown("slow") } ); 
});
```

What i would want to do is to make sure that all divs that are named:

1. div.1
2. div.2 **EXCEPT THIS ONE**
3. div.3
4. div.4
5. div.5

is slided up, except the second div.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the [not](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/not) selector to prevent one (or more) of them from sliding up:

```
$("div#personal").click(function() { 
  $("div :not('#idofseconddiv'").slideUp("slow");
});
```

It would be a good idea to give those divs a common css class so the selector does not select all divs in your page:

```
$("div#personal").click(function() { 
  $("div.someClass :not('#idofseconddiv')").slideUp("slow");
});
```

If you are using numbered class names on your divs, you might want to consider using the [starts with attribute filter](http://docs.jquery.com/Selectors/attributeStartsWith):

```
$("div#personal").click(function() { 
  $("div[class^=yourClass] :not('#idofseconddiv')").slideUp("slow");
});
```

Comment: those divs have classes and in those classes it is 1 to 5.

Comment: Use also the jQuery object accessor INDEX if you don't have an ID. It returns the index (based zero) of that div in the page

Comment: Yes, but how do make sure that all my divs with the classes 1 to 5 are slided up? This only makes sure 1 div with someClass is slided up and not all.

Comment: @Elijah Woods - then maybe use the starts with attribute filter, e.g. $('div[class^=someClass] not:('#idofseconddiv')") where someClass is what your classes start with, before the number, e.g. myClass if you have myClass1, myClass2, etc.

Comment: Great karim79! The starts with attribute filter was awesome :p

Comment: can I also do an AND to this NOT? how do I do it sir?